# How to execute multiple commands interactively in linux terminal from Java?

Tags: java, linux, terminal, torch

I want to run multiple commands in the `linux terminal` and that will be one like as follows:

**1.** I will run suppose `torch` and i wrote `th` command and it opened the torch promt.

**2.** Now if i execute next command from java then it will run in the torch promt of the linux terminal.
 ***you can take another example like:***
**1.** At fist i will run `python` in the linux terminal from java.
**2.** Then run `1+1` or anything in the python interpreter from java.
So here my second command is dependent on the first command. I want to run the commands in the terminal in a sequential way.

**Edit**: Another approach will do.Suppose i have a python interpreter running in linux terminal and now i want to execute a command from java that will run in the python interpreter of that particular opened linux terminal. **Can i do that??**

I have tried to to run a command using this:

```
        String line;
            try
            {

                String execstr= "th"; //It opens the torch promt in linux terminal.

                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execstr);
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                /*if((line= input.readLine())==null)
                    System.out.println("blank");*/

                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                input.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

But now after this command how can i run a command from java in the promt that means i want it interactively ??

**So how can i save the state of the previous command and use it for the next command??**

Answer (score 0):

Use `p.getOutputStream()` to get a stream into which you can write the desired input for the program you run. (I know, the naming is a bit confusing).

Just the relevant part:

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execstr);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    OutputStream ops = p.getOutputStream();
    ops.write("echo hello world".getBytes());
    ops.close();            

    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
    {
       System.out.println(line);
    }
    input.close();
```

Comment: If i write th in the linux terminal it will open a th interpreter and i have a model of torch7 running in that interpreter..Now i want to run another command in that th interpreter which is ran before from java

Comment: what is actually i am doing here in p.getOutputStream and ops.write() function?? can i run a  command to a opened terminal in linux from java??

Comment: I don't know your answer even suits my question or not??

Comment: whatever you write into `ops` is the input for the process p; in your example, it is used as the input to `th`

Comment: I'm also unsure, because your question is a bit difficult to understand, sorry :-/

Comment: Then how to get the result after running that??

Comment: instead of `System.out.println(line);`, collect the lines e.g. in a stringbuilder

Comment: Ok let me explain to u.. suppose i have a terminal open with running torch..and in torch i am loading a model which will be used when i will execute another command from java in this terminal.. Now how can i do that?? Or you can think of like that i have a python interpreter running in linux terminal and i will just exec the 1+1 command from java in that opened terminal..

Comment: I tried to ran like this but not output.. check the link http://paste.ubuntu.com/15669621/ . Am i missing anything??